# Difference among several ways of creating string

Tags: java, string, string-pool

Several ways of creating string are shown below. Questions are added following the expressions in the way of comments.

```
String str = "test";
String str1 = new String(str);  //Will it invoke the Constructor of String(String)?
String str2 = new String("test");//Will it invoke the Constructor of String(String)?
String str3 = str; //Which Constructor will it invoke? Or str3 only reference to str and "test" without being constructed?
String str4 = "test";//Which Constructor will it invoke? Or str4 only reference to str and "test" without being constructed?
String strnew = new String("testnew");//Will this expression create "testnew" in String Constant Pool before it creates strnew?
```

One additional question: Is there any difference bwtween the ways of creating str3 and str4?

Comment: there is no difference in creating str3 and str4 - they all will get a reference to a string object from the pool

Comment: This isn't that bad of a question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Whenever you call `new` in JAVA it create an object in heap and obviously it will call the constructor also.
>
> String literals will go to `String Constant Pool`.

It might help you to understand it visually.

[image]

Comment: I have read this figure. I still have the questions shown above. Can you have a look at them?

Comment: Sure. First read two lines of my post.

Comment: "String literals will go to String Constant Pool". So the expression "String strnew = new String("testnew")" will create "testnew" in String Constant Pool before it creates strnew?

Comment: String literal `"testnew"` will go to String constant pool and `strnew` will go to heap. Look at first example of the diagram.

Comment: Thank you very much! And about str3 and str4, Which Constructor will it invoke? or they are just references to "test"?

Comment: for `str3` and `str4` no constructor is called. They are just referencing to the existing String.

Comment: **Remember** constructor is called only when you called it via `new` keyword.

Comment: My pleasure. You're most welcome. you can remember for longer time using Visually representation most probably for your next interview :)